# spark streaming DirectKafkaInputDStream: kafka data source can easily stress the driver node

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am building a prototype with spark streaming 1.5.0. `DirectKafkaInputDStream` is used.

And a simple stage to read from kafka by `DirectKafkaInputDStream` can't handle massive amount of messages. The stage spends longer time then batch interval, once the message rate reach or exceed a certain value. And the rate is much lower than I expect. ( I have done another benchmark of my kafka cluster with multiple consumer instances in different servers)

```
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> recipeDStream =
        KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc, 
            String.class, 
            String.class, 
            StringKeyDecoder.class,
            StringDecoder.class,
            kafkaParams, kafkaTopicsSet);
```

After reading this [article](http://www.spark.tc/custom-spark-streaming-dstreams-and-receivers/), I realize that the `DirectKafkaInputDStream` is run  on the same node as the driver program. is it ture? If so, then `DirectKafkaInputDStream` can easily be stressed as it read all message in one node then dispatch to all executors.

And it means `JavaPairReceiverInputDStream` has better performance in handling high volume data, since receivers runs on multiple executor instances.

Am I right? Can someone explain this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, the direct stream is only communicating from the driver to kafka in order to find the latest available offsets.  Actual messages are read only on the executors.

Switching .createStream to .createDirectStream should in general perform better, not worse.  If you've got a small reproducible example to the contrary, please share it on the spark mailing list or jira.